How to use firebase storage in spring mvc for upload image
I have configured firebase realtime database and firebase storage but only the realtime database can be used and when I use the storage it gives me a 401 unauthorized error.
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bookstore-47b38.appspot.com/o?projection=full&uploadType=multipart
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:233)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:314)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:218)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.internalCreate(StorageImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:171)
    at com.springmvc.firebase.FirebaseStorageService.uploadFile(FirebaseStorageService.java:23)
    at com.springmvc.controller.admin.AdminSlideController.handleFileUpload(AdminSlideController.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bookstore-47b38.appspot.com/o?projection=full&uploadType=multipart
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:532)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:311)
    ... 52 more


Below is my firebase configuration:
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public FirebaseApp firebaseApp() throws IOException {
        String databaseUrl = "https://bookstore-47b38-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app";
        String storageBucket = "bookstore-47b38.appspot.com";
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/firebase/serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(resource.getInputStream()))
                .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
                .setStorageBucket(storageBucket)
                .build();

        return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }

    @Bean
    public Storage firebaseStorage(FirebaseApp firebaseApp) {
        return StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId(firebaseApp.getOptions().getProjectId())
                .build()
                .getService();
    }

    @Bean
    public FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase() throws IOException {
        return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp());
    }
}

@Autowired
private Storage firebaseStorage;
private String bucketName = "bookstore-47b38.appspot.com";

public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, fileName).build();
    firebaseStorage.create(blobInfo, file.getBytes());
    return "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
}

<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
     <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
     <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Can someone help me correct the error or suggest another solution that can use firebase storage in this case. Thanks a lot.
